# Using pagination in fat model skinny controller scenario

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to convert this CakePHP tutorial I'm working on to the *fat model skinny controller* concept. However, I can't seem to use the pagination option.

I have a method in the model that grabs all entries from the table and when I call `$this->paginate($this->Posts->getAllPosts());` it throws out an error.

Any pointers to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way, you should pass the same params into the `$this->paginate` en then call your pagination using `$this->paginate('Post')`

[CakePHP Paginate Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup)

Edit: You shouldn't use pagination from the model, if anything you could make a function that builds the conditions and feed it to your `$this->paginate` before you call `$this->paginate('Post')`